# If statements inside MsgBox

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Does anyone have a way of including if statements inside of a msgbox in VBA? I can’t seem to find a suitable solution by searching…

To explain, let’s say that I have three cells, a1 and a2 and if any of these are empty I want a word to be included in a msgbox.

So I want something like

```
Sub xx
  Msgbox if a1 = "" include "word one" end if &  if a2="" include "word two" end if
End sub
```

I know I can do it with `if` statements outside of the msgbox, but my problem is a bit larger and would require over 1000 combinations.

Comment: You'll hit the limitation for statement/line continuation length ***long*** before you'll get 1000 nested `If`s into one string... What are you trying to achieve?  There's probably a much better solution.

Comment: `MsgBox IIf(a1 = "", "word one", "") & IIf(a2 = "", "word two", "")`, but that will win you nothing compared to incrementally building a string with `if`s.

Comment: Look into using `IIF()` (VBA's version of the ternary operator)

Comment: @Comintern as I said, 1000 combinations, not 1000 if-statements.

Comment: @GSerg then how do I build a string with if-statements? That would achive the same thing if I can change the command msgbox for string.

Comment: So 2^10 or 10 conditions?  That's still a ***ton*** of logic to build into a string concatenation.

Comment: These two things aren't mutually exclusive so it's not one or the other.. is you logic something like this: if A1 is empty and A2 has a value then "word one", if A1 is empty and A2 is also empty then "word one word two" and if A1 has a value and A2 is empty then "Word two"???

Comment: Ok, so you want to loop through and concatenate based on whether of not a cell has a value - if so, what are these "word one" and "word two" strings (or are these literals?) if they're literals, does it just go in word increments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MsgBox` Takes a string as first argument. So you cannot include statements like `If` in it. However you could use `If` to build a string and pass that string to `MsgBox` Like this:

```
Sub xx()
    Dim message As String
    If a1 = "" Then
        message = "word one"
    End If
    If a2 = "" then
        message = message & "word two"
    End if
    MsgBox message
 End Sub
```

Or if you really want it in a single line, you can Use [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) which is *kind of* an inline if (there are important difference but they do not matter in your specific use case)

```
Sub xx()
    MsgBox IIF(a1 = "", "word one","") & IIF(a2="", "word two", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: that should do it. Thank you

Comment: @D.Loo, if this answer satisfies your needs, then don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox "I include " & IIf(Range("a1") = "", "word one", "") & IIf(Range("a2") = "", "word two", "")
```

but be aware that [IIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264412(v=office.15).aspx) function *" evaluates both truepart and falsepart, even though it returns only one of them."* so that if any evaluated range returns an error then the whole statement returns an error

Comment: Would the _brave_ downvoter show up and give any explanation so as to both have people know why they shouldn't follow thi answer and teach me how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could work with an array that checks all cells in a range with an array IF, then produces a custom message (which could return a matching range of words, or in the sample below, the row number where the cell is blank)

*code*

```
Sub SloaneDog()
Dim strIn As String
strIn = Join(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(A1:A20= """",""Word "" & ROW(A1:A20),""X"")")), "X", False), vbNewLine)
MsgBox strIn, vbYesNo, "words"
End Sub
```

[image]